# Kendo dropdownlist reinitialize issue

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have a dropdownlist as :

```
<select class="kendo-select">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

And in JS as :

```
$('.kendo-select').kendoDropDownList();
```

How do I re-initialize the dataSource of this dropdown as I haven't used dataSource while creating the dropdown ?

I have tried adding kendoDropDownList again after a successful ajax call but doing that triggers ajax calls multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.kendo-select').data('kendoDropDownList').dataSource.data(result);//where result is your data need to load
```

Comment: Although this code might help, a good answer should always explain what the problem is and how the code helps.